# dynamically cloning a LinearLayout in android?

Tags: android

Say I have a LinearLayout with some elements in it as an .xml file.
In Java, I need to somehow "clone" it a few times into an array, edit some of its children, and then loop through the array, adding each LinearLayout to my main view.

What do you think would be the correct way to "clone" this layout from an xml file into an array element in java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutId, null);
```

you can do some thing like this to inflate the view, and then modify the element iside the view using the findViewById method.  Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing, how do I address a child of a newly cloned element?

Comment: okay  v.findViewById(R.id.yourChildId) this will give you the child reference

Comment: Is it possible to clone a View created programmatically without an xml file? With the LayoutInflator?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
....
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout layout = null;
for(....) {
   layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_ID, null); 
   someList.add(layout); 
}
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the layout in a variable:

```
for (int c=0; c < count; c++)
{
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourmainlayout);
    // do something with layout
    // assign layout to a variable or add it on another layout
}
```