# Dynamically create and add framelayouts android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have created a framelayout having a button and 3 textviews inside the button. I want to duplicate this and add them dynamically through the java program one below the other.

The xml code for the same is attached.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">        
    <Button android:layout_width="319dp" android:layout_height="130dp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/app_name"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/app_name"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/app_name"/>  
  </FrameLayout>
  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout2" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/frameLayout1">        
    <Button android:layout_width="319dp" android:layout_height="130dp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/app_name"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView5" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/app_name"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView6" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/app_name"/>  
  </FrameLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

The java code for this duplication and appending to the end is given by,

```
FrameLayout f2 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);
        FrameLayout f3;
        f3 = f2;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.frameLayout2);
        f3.setLayoutParams(p);
```

I want the 3rd frame layout to be placed below the second one, but running this code, the second frame layout is also not visible, could anyone tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: This is java, by writing f3 = f2 you are just referencing f3 to f2, so this is not a duplicate. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807650/dynamically-cloning-a-linearlayout-in-android

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, will this work for framelayouts?? I mean, i dont want to clone the entire relative layout but only a segment.

Comment: I'm guessing that yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract the frame layout in a separate button_and_text.xml file and then use the [include tag](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <include layout="@layout/button_and_text" android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"/>
    <include layout="@layout/button_and_text" android:id="@+id/frameLayout2" android:layout_below="@id/frameLayout1"/>
```